# example of a sequence in $C[0,1]$ which converges in weighted sup norm but not in L1 norm

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I am trying to think of a sequence $\lbrace f_n \rbrace$ in $C[0,1]$ which converges in the weighted supremum norm $$\|f\| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|xf(x)|$$ but not in the L1 norm 
$$\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|\ dx.$$

How do I construct such a sequence?

Comment: How about letting $f_n(x)=0$ on $[\frac 1n, 1]$, and $f_n(x)=\frac {1}{x|\ln x|}-\frac{n}{\ln n}$ on $[\epsilon_n, \frac 1n]$, where $\epsilon_n$ is chosen so that if we define $f_n(x)=\frac {1}{\epsilon_n|\ln \epsilon_n|}-\frac{n}{\ln n}$ on $[0, \epsilon_n]$ we would have $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=n$. Then $f_n$ converges to $0$ in the weighted norm.

Comment: @YuDing, how is this function continuous in $x=0$?

Comment: $f_n$ on $[0, \epsilon_n]$ is the constant $f_n(\epsilon_n)$ given by the above value...

Comment: Oh. I missed it. That's right!

Comment: @YuDing thanks - can you explain _how_ you thought of this example?

Comment: Oh, we wish some function $u$ that is NOT $L^1$ but satisfying $xu(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, so $\frac{1}{x|\ln x|}$ is a natural choice...